# AWS Aurora mySQL DB lost external connections when I deleted a serverless DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection, external, amazon-aurora

I had both an Aurora mySql and a serverless DB running at the same time using the same security groups/subnets in the same default VPC.  I recently deleted the serverless DB and shortly after I found that I can no longer connect to the Aurora DB from my local computer. The connection from the EC2 application to the DB is working fine.

I've been looking at the security groups but can't seem to see the issue. (the publicly accessible flag is yes)

Here's the security rules attached to the DB
[image]

I'm able to ping the IP that's in the 1st row of the image.